# how to retrieve a value by clicking and retrieve the id?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to make a function that allows me by clicking on the square with the id of colors, in return me id = " retours_couleurs " the sentence containing the colors contained in the table in php files, sorry for my english i'm french

this is my html code

```
<fieldset class="appel">
        <code>
            Un clic simple sur le carré bleu appelle le contenu du fichier couleurs.php, en transmettant en paramètre l'ID de ce carré. La réponse du fichier appelé devra s'afficher dans l'espace prévu à cet effet (id="retour_couleurs").
        </code>
    </fieldset>
    <br />
    <fieldset class="appel">
        <div class="carre-couleurs">
            <div class="carre" id="jaune"></div>
            <div class="carre" id="rouge"></div>
            <div class="carre" id="bleu"></div>
            <div class="carre" id="vert"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <fieldset class="retour">
            <legend>Contenu du fichier</legend>
            <div id="retour_couleurs"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
```

this is my ajax function

```
function appel_contenue_couleur(){
                var cM = new XMLHttpRequest();
        cM.open("POST","fichiers/couleurs.php",true);
        cM.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var couleur = this.id;
    var retour_couleurs = document.getElementById('retour_couleurs');
        cM.send("retour= "+couleur);
        cM.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if (cM.readyState == 4 && cM.status == 200)
        {
            retour_couleurs.innerHTML=cM.responseText;
        }
        }}
```

and this is my php code

```
$_couleurs = array("jaune", "rouge", "bleu", "vert");

$_citations = array(
    "L’herbe est toujours plus verte ailleurs",
    "La terre est bleue comme une orange",
    "Le ciel est un oeuf, la terre en est le jaune",
    "Mieux vaut rester rouge cinq minutes que jaune toute la vie",
    "C'était un moustique snob. Il ne buvait que du sang bleu"
);
$couleurs = $_POST['retour'];
if (in_array($couleurs,$_couleurs)){
    for ($i=0;$i<count($_citations);$i++){
        if (in_array ($couleurs,$_citations[$i])){
            echo $_citations[$i];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not use links <a href="couleurs.php?color=RGB"> in place of posting datas ?
And , in place of using two arrays for both colors and citations, why not use an assosiative array ?
(Je parle francais, je pense que ta question n'est pas très bien expliquée en anglais, essaye de la reformuler..)

Comment: @microbe Why would he use links if he wants to get asynchronous data? And the array for the citations it's because there are more citations than colors, and some citations contains more than one color. The goal is to output all the citations containing a certain color.

Comment: @MaxArt You're totally right, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete code:
Javascript:

```
function appel_contenue_couleur(obj){


                var cM = new XMLHttpRequest();
        cM.open("POST","colors.php",true);
        cM.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var couleur = obj.id;

    var retour_couleurs = document.getElementById('retour_couleurs');
        cM.send("retour= "+couleur);
        cM.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if (cM.readyState == 4 && cM.status == 200)
        {
           retour_couleurs.innerHTML=cM.responseText;
        }
        }}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="carre-couleurs">
            <div class="carre" id="jaune" onclick="appel_contenue_couleur(this);">1111111</div>
            <div class="carre" id="rouge" onclick="appel_contenue_couleur(this);">222222222</div>
            <div class="carre" id="bleu" onclick="appel_contenue_couleur(this);">33333333</div>
            <div class="carre" id="vert" onclick="appel_contenue_couleur(this);">444444444444</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

PHP:

```
$colors = array("jaune", "rouge", "bleu", "vert");
$citations = array(
    "L’herbe est toujours plus verte ailleurs",
    "La terre est bleue comme une orange",
    "Le ciel est un oeuf, la terre en est le jaune",
    "Mieux vaut rester rouge cinq minutes que jaune toute la vie",
    "C'était un moustique snob. Il ne buvait que du sang bleu"
);
$color = trim($_POST['retour']);

//echo $color;

if (in_array($color,$colors)){



   for($i=0;$i<count($citations);$i++) {

  if(stripos($citations[$i],$color)!==false) {


       echo $citations[$i].'<br>';


   }
   }
        }
```

It is working, 100%, it's tested. Just change links, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you're not getting any output from the AJAX request. That's probably because you're using the wrong PHP function to check if a sentence contains a certain word.

Try with this one:

```
if (stripos($_citations[$i], $couleurs) !== false) {
    echo $_citations[$i];
}
```

I used [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.stripos.php) because you probably don't want to make a case sensitive check.

Comment: after trying its not work  so i try with another , its work but i have just output for jaune and bleu the other colors don't work, i try with this ` $couleurs = $_POST['retour'];
    for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
        if ($couleurs==$_couleurs[$i]){
            for ($j=0;$j<5;$j++){
                if ($couleurs==strstr($_citations[$j],$couleurs)){
                    echo $_citations[j];`

Comment: @SidiALIOUSSENI Why are you using `strstr`? It's totally not the right function here. Or it *may* be, but instead of `if ($coleurs==strstr(...))`, try with `if (strstr(...) !== false)`. It worked for "bleu" and "jaune" because they're at the end of the phrase, [check the specs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php).

Comment: @SidiALIOUSSENI, use stripos, as suggested, AND, please add this to your php: $couleurs = trim($_POST['retour']);, OR - change your javascript (cM.send("retour= "+couleur); -> you have one empty space there, trim will take care about it, anyway)

Comment: thanks you my friend its work so i used this : $couleurs = trim($_POST['retour']);
    for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
        if ($couleurs==$_couleurs[$i]){
            for ($j=0;$j<5;$j++){
                if (stripos($_citations[$j], $couleurs) !== false) {
                    echo $_citations[$j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

?> but when i click its give me two sentence for example for jaune i have two sentence, but its work :D